# Find a database with a particular table OR Find a table in every database of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server with hundreds of databases and each database having hundreds of tables.
Now I would like to find where in these databases is a table that I am looking for.

I could find if a table existed in individual database using

```
use myDatabase 
select * from sys.tables  where name = 'mytable' 
GO
```

but using this means I have to manually change the database for hundreds of times .
I would like to find the database name only.
Is there a way out ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sp_MSforeachdb query help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837673/sp-msforeachdb-query-help)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The same system stored procedure can be used in the solution but the question is not the same in my opinion.

Comment: @John Sansom - the title of the other question is poorly worded, but it is dealing with finding and working with a table in each database on a server, where there are other DBs on the server which will not have this table. I thought it was close enough.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This questions is interested to find the database with a given table , hence i think it is significantly different.

Comment: sorry, I was obviously reading too much into your question. Usually I find that this is the first part of the longer question "... and having found the databases containing this table, how do I query that table in each db".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay, if you're just wanting to find each database that contains a particular table, and aren't going to be querying the table, then you can just do:

```
create table #t (
    DBName sysname not null
)
go
exec sp_MSforeachdb 'use [?]; if OBJECT_ID(''dbo.mytable'') is not null insert into #t (DBName) select ''?'''
go
select * from #t
go
drop table #t
```

(If you're not using multiple schemas in your databases, you won't need to specify dbo in the `OBJECT_ID` call, otherwise I use it to avoid finding tables in the wrong schema)

Comment: [It is possible to do this without #temp tables and sp_msforeachdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733170/find-a-database-with-a-particular-table-or-find-a-table-in-every-database-of-sql/5365215#5365215)

Comment: @Martin - TBH, I think I'd just re-purposed another answer which was querying the table in each database.

Answer (score 14):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb "use [?];select * from sys.tables where name='TableName' "
```

To include the name of the current database in the output use:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb "use [?];select '[?]' as DatabaseName, * from sys.tables where name='TableName' "
```

Comment: The sql executed ,but I could not get the database name from it .

Comment: @Thunder so you want the database name to be output in the result set also?

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  DB_NAME(database_id)
FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_operational_stats](NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id,database_id) = 'mytable'
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but was high on my google search.  So I wanted to contribute for others looking to find a database with a certain table in it.  These apply to SQL Server 2008 - Current.

I started with this, which worked for my SA level login, but gave me issues with users that did not have permissions to all databases.

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE CASE
WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' THEN OBJECT_ID( QUOTENAME( name ) + '.[dbo].[mytablename]','U' )
END IS NOT NULL;
```

But ended up with this adding the `HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1` in restriction so that the query would not fail with a security error.

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1 and
CASE
WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' THEN OBJECT_ID( QUOTENAME( name ) + '.[dbo].[mytablename]','U' )
END IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: For tables in the default / known schema this is great!

Answer (score 1):

```
exec sp_msforeachdb @command1='     
USE ?;
select * from sys.tables where name = ''CLIENTS'''
```

Answer (score 0):

this is also one of the way, similar with solution of @Jonathan :

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb 'SELECT "?" AS DB, * FROM [?].sys.tables WHERE name like ''%YourTableName%'''
```

Answer (score -1):

```
exec 'select ''?'', name from [?].sys.tables where name = ''yourTable'''
```

Comment: i guess you want to write this sp_MSforeachdb 'SELECT "?" AS DB, * FROM [?].sys.tables WHERE name like ''%yourtable ame%'''