# Failing to understand how to select all rows based on table- and database-name

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, cursor

> **WHAT I EXPECT:**

I want to create a Job in my SQL Server Agent that allows me to fire off a stored procedure to clean up a particular table. The spu would take two parameters: `TableName` and `Days`.

TableName would be the name of the table I'm looking for and Days would be how far back I wish to delete records.

> **WHAT I'VE DONE:**

After having looked around online I've found sources on how to see if a User Database holds the supplied TableName:

`SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName`

This results in a few rows looking a bit like this:

`TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA |TABLE_NAME |TABLE_TYPE
Database_A    | table_schema |table_A    |table_type`

> **WHAT I DON'T UNDERSTAND:**

How can I use the resulting rows of the previous query to find all rows of the supplied `@TableName` in a particular Database? In pseudo:

`SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE database = database_A`

I know I need to use a cursor somehow, **that's not the problem**.

What I'm simply struggling to understand is how I can use the database name and the table name to find the rows of the table in a particular database.

In my case I've got 10 or so databases that need to be iterated through to find the initial dataset (all user databases where `@TableName` exists) and then a **secondary query** to find all rows of the `@TableName` in the database that the cursor currently is pointing at.

Comment: Post the queries please. But, you are going to need dynamic SQL most likely. The issue you are going to run into I think is when you load your cursor into a vairable, like @TableToDeleteFrom and try `DELETE FROM @TableToDeleteFrom`. This isn't going to work. You'll have to build a dynamic SQL Statement with the concatenated string.

Comment: Here are two great answers that are similar to your post. [Damien using forEachDB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4733452/6167855) and [Pinal using a different method](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/29/sql-server-find-table-in-every-database-of-sql-server/)

Answer (score -1):

You have to do select * from ..table_A 
but you can't do that in a a simple TSQL. Possibly you could generate a sub script and execute.

Comment: This is not an answer.